# Matching string inside file and returning result

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell, grep

I've got a few peculiar issues with trying to search for a string inside of a `.db` file. The way I tried was by using grep, which does apparently find the string(s), although this is the output:

```
$ grep "ext" *.db
Binary file enormous.db matches
```

There are a couple problems with this:

1. I need to return the actual matching string.
2. I only want to return a particular string out of the matching ones
3. The filename changes, so it's only the extensions match
4. The are more than one valid extension (ext, bin, fck)

> The thing that differentiates the string I'm looking for apart from
>   the others is that it always contains some random character followed
>   by a hexadecimal 02, then the filename.

[image: /File One.ext÷ïAnother File.ext#TheFile.ext◊®®®®® Another.extÆππ∫ MoreFiles.ext|Random.extª@N&Q/Path/To Some/file.ext]

In the above horrid mess of gunk is **TheFile.ext**, which I'm hoping to grab (hex is shown below). Maybe grep isn't the right tool for this particular task? I'm not sure, but open to ideas - thanks.

```
2F46696C65204F6E652E65787400D60F950017416E6F746865722046696C652E657874001003230254686546696C652E65787400D70FA80FA80FA80FA8000F0FA80020416E6F746865722E65787400AE0FB9000FB9000FBA00204D6F726546696C65732E6578747C00000000000000000E52616E646F6D2E65787400BB0C030701404E00000000000003260351012F506174682F546F20536F6D652F66696C652E657874
```

Comment: Try: `grep --binary-files=text -oP '[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.ext' *.db` I'm assuming that the filename only contains `[A-Za-z0-9_]` Change it as you require.

Comment: @anishsane, unfortunately i don't think my grep is the same... this is on osx. `grep --binary-files=text -o '[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.ext' *.db` did return a result, although it was the very last one... `file.ext`

Comment: Be very careful!  Extracting text strings from a binary file is not always meaningful.  For example: for performance reasons, a database might not actually delete a data entry when requested but instead mark that record as "reusable" or "free".  Since you don't know the internal data structure, and you are ignoring the non-text data as "random" (which seems unlikely), you have no idea if the data you are extracting is valid.  You should really use database functions to get the data.

Comment: @cdarke, I completely agree with you... and I'm beginning to think there might not be an 'easy' solution to this, since there doesn't seem to be a reliable way of getting the string. Unfortunately I don't have the slightest clue on how to query this db file for the string I'm looking for.

Comment: What type of db is it?  Do you know how it was created: SQLite?  You can try: `file *.db`.  Are you on OS X?

Comment: @RoryZipher: I'm on OS X myself, so if it is a standard file I could have a hack myself, but it will have to be later.  Let me know.

Comment: Is the `strings` command available in OS X?  This will extract the printable strings from the binary, and you may get better results running `grep` on the output of that.

Comment: @rojomoke, yes the strings command is available on osx, and i've been using it in combination with grep, but it's still returning more results than the one i need.

Comment: I've had a play and posted - I hope it helps.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sqlite3` from bash on OS X seems fairly straightforward (I'm no expert at this, by the way).

You will need to find out which table you need.  You can do this with an interactive session.  I'll show you with the database you suggested:

```
/Users/fredbloggs> sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
data         displays     pictures     preferences  prefs        spaces     
sqlite> select * from data;
/Library/Desktop Pictures/Earth and Moon.jpg
sqlite> .exit
```

How did I know it was table `data`?  I didn't, I tried each one until it looked right :-)

Now we need to run that from a bash script:

```
cmd='select * from data'
fname=$(sqlite3 $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "$cmd")

echo "filenames are: $fname"
```

Gotchas:  seemed to be an issue with `~`.  I kept forgetting to `\` the space in "Application Support".

Give that a try, and see where we get.  Let me know!

Comment: @RoryZipher: excellent!  I'm sure this is better than messing with `strings` and `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` varies a lot between platforms. Here's how you can do it on GNU and presumably on OS X:

```
$ grep -ao '[[:print:]]*\.ext' file.bin
/File One.ext
Another File.ext
TheFile.ext
 Another.ext
 MoreFiles.ext
Random.ext
/Path/To Some/file.ext
```

If you find that it doesn't work, please say which platform you are trying to use it on.

Comment: I was just searching if there is something like `[[:print"]]`. :-) +1

Comment: sorry, i should have specified, it's on osx. the command you've shown returns the last result `Q/Path/To Some/file.ext`. I tried `strings -ao *.db | grep "ext"` which seems similar to your results which is promising. I'm still unsure how to pick out the right file though with what is returned - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-a` option to make `grep` output the matches from binary files. You can reduce the output to just the file name if you know what type of characters make up the filename.

```
grep -ao '[[:print:]]*\.ext' *.db
```

For different file extensions, well, you need to create a list of files. You can use find

```
find . <search criteria> -exec grep -aoH '[[:print:]]*\.ext' {} \+
```

*Updated to make use of the `[[:print:]]` search term that I hadn't known before.*

Comment: `[:print:]` is called a POSIX character class.  There are a number of them and they can be combined inside square brackets, e.g.: `[[:alpha:][:punct:]]`